# Trouble with Show/Hide code, second level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the text under Sub1 and Sub2, do not show the text under them, when clicking them. Only the first link "Main Category" functions. It is making me enter more description, though the issue is already explained the best I know how.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
session_start();
print "
<html>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#body {
font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
display:none;
width: 100%;
padding: 5px 0;
text-align: left;
background-color: lightblue;
margin-top: 5px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="body12">
<a href='#' class='articleTitle'><font size="+1">Main Category</font></a>
<div class='showArticle'>
<a href='#' class='commentsTitle'><font size="+1">Sub1</font></a>
<div class='showComments'>
<font size="+1" color="red"><b>Text1</b></font>
</div><br>
<a href='#' class='commentsTitle'><font size="+1">Sub2</font></a>
<div class='showComments'>
<font size="+1" color="red"><b>Text2</b></font>
</div></div><br>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.showArticle').hide();
$('.articleTitle').show();

$('.showComments').hide();
$('.commentTitle').show();

$('.articleTitle').click(function(e){
$(this).next('.showArticle').slideToggle();
e.preventDefault();
});

$('.commentTitle').click(function(e){
$(this).next('.showComments').slideToggle();
e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's no coincidence that you are having trouble with levels and sub-levels and that all your code exists at one indentation level. Really. Fix the indentation and it will be easier to fix the coding issue.

Comment: You have a spelling error, in your html it's `class="commentsTitle"` but in your code it `$('.commentTitle')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your JS `$('.commentsTitle').click(...` 
In the html you assigned the class `commentsTitle`, in the JS, you referred to `commentTitle`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.showArticle').hide();
$('.articleTitle').show();

$('.showComments').hide();
$('.commentsTitle').show();

$('.articleTitle').click(function(e){
$(this).next('.showArticle').slideToggle();
e.preventDefault();
});

$('.commentsTitle').click(function(e){
$(this).next('.showComments').slideToggle();
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```html
<body>
<div id="body12">
<a href='#' class='articleTitle'><font size="+1">Main Category</font></a>
<div class='showArticle'>
<a href='#' class='commentsTitle'><font size="+1">Sub1</font></a>
<div class='showComments'>
<font size="+1" color="red"><b>Text1</b></font>
</div><br>
<a href='#' class='commentsTitle'><font size="+1">Sub2</font></a>
<div class='showComments'>
<font size="+1" color="red"><b>Text2</b></font>
</div></div><br>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it had to be a very simple issue. I just couldn't see it.

Comment: No problem. If it has solved your issue, please mark this answer as solved. Thanks.